# Difference Between angularjs .run() and $apply()

Tags: angularjs

Is the Angularjs function ***.run()*** and ***$scope.$apply();*** are very similar, I was going through the documents and felt like both perform nearly similar actions.

Are they different, Or am i correct, Please correct me if i am wrong.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are actually not similar at all. The .run() is a module that runs after all the services and injections are finished (similar to a main()), and the $apply() is a function that forces a digest cycle to run. This is typically used when using outside libraries or directives that update data, but do not inherently update the dom/view.

Comment: @ZackArgyle, Hey, thanks dude, but i just want to know a little more, if you do not mind answering it. take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/AzR9x/1/ , In this if we can setInterval(function() {console.log(hi);},1000);, then why setInterval(function() {updateClock();},1000); will not work, appling $scope.$apply works

Comment: Great question. The reason is that setInterval runs your function outside of the Angular scope, so it does not fire a digest cycle. $scope.$apply forces the digest which updates the view. The alternative is to use the $interval service built into Angular. It essentially does the same thing.